# Dropdown field should become editable after clicking the edit button

Tags: javascript, python, html, django-rest-framework, html-select

I am trying to build an interactive website using Django Framework, HTML and JavaScript. Basically, I have a POST form that accepts submissions and sends them to the Database. The same page also populates the submissions.

Two of the fields in the submissions model have a foreign key reference to Consultant_ID and Recruirer_ID. Please see the image below.

[image: Front End]

Now, you will see the edit/Delete button based on the Recruiter_ID (inherited from AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin) who is logged in. Only his/her submissions will have an edit button. When I click the edit button, all the text fields are editable but I dont see a dropdown show up for Recruiter_ID and Consultant_ID. I want the dropdown to reappear for a submission when I click edit.

Please see the below image when I try to edit the submission. The JavaScript output in the console will show you undefined for the two foreign key fields. But you can still see the available options for a consultant_ID. I am just not able to render a dropdown and change consultant.

[image]

Below is my HTML for the form and JS Code Snippet (to generate options and update the field)

```
<h2>Create a New Submission</h2>
<form method="post" action="{% url 'submissions-list' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <label for="dos">DOS:</label>
    <input type="date" name="dos" id="dos" value="{{ today|date:'Y-m-d' }}" required>
    <br>

    <label for="recruiter_{{submission.id}}">Recruiter:</label>
    <select name="recruiter" id="recruiter_{{submission.id}}" style="width: 200px;">
        {% for r in recruiters %}
        <option value="{{ r.R_Id }}">{{ r.R_UserName }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <br>

    <label for="consultant_{{submission.id}}">Consultant:</label>
    <select name="consultant" id="consultant_{{submission.id}}">
        {% for consultant in consultants %}
        <option value="{{ consultant.C_Id }}">{{ consultant.C_Name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <br>

    <label for="consultant_job_title">Consultant Job Title:</label>
    <input type="text" name="consultant_job_title" id="consultant_job_title">
    <br>

    <label for="implementation_partner">Implementation Partner:</label>
    <input type="text" name="implementation_partner" id="implementation_partner">
    <br>

    <label for="end_client">End Client:</label>
    <input type="text" name="end_client" id="end_client">
    <br>

    <label for="end_client_location">End Client Location:</label>
    <input type="text" name="end_client_location" id="end_client_location">
    <br>

    <label for="implementation_partner_name">Implementation Partner Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="implementation_partner_name" id="implementation_partner_name">
    <br>

    <label for="implementation_partner_contact">Implementation Partner Contact:</label>
    <input type="text" name="implementation_partner_contact" id="implementation_partner_contact">
    <br>

    <!-- Add more fields as needed -->

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
    var recruitersData = JSON.parse('{{ json_recruiters|escapejs }}');
    var consultantsData = JSON.parse('{{ json_consultants|escapejs }}');
    console.log('In the HTML: ',typeof (recruitersData));
    console.log('In the HTML: ', typeof (consultantsData));
    function handleEditButtonClick(submissionID) {
        editSubmission(submissionID, '{{ user }}');
        //initializeDropdowns(recruitersData, consultantsData, submissionID, '{{ user }}');
    }
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is my JS Code.

```
function initializeDropdowns(recruitersData, consultantsData, submissionID,user ) {
    var recruiterElement = document.getElementById('recruiter_' + submissionID);
    var consultantElement = document.getElementById('consultant_' + submissionID);

    // Clear the existing options in the dropdowns
    recruiterElement.innerHTML = '';
    consultantElement.innerHTML = '';

    // Populate the recruiter dropdown
    recruitersData.forEach(recruiter => {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = user;
        option.text = recruiter.R_Name;
        recruiterElement.appendChild(option);
    });

    // Populate the consultant dropdown
    consultantsData.forEach(consultant => {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = consultant.C_Id;
        option.text = consultant.C_Name;
        consultantElement.appendChild(option);
    });
    console.log(recruiterElement);
    console.log(consultantElement);
}


function editSubmission(submissionID, user) {
    console.log('In the edit button')
    var dosElement = document.getElementById('dos_' + submissionID);
    var recruiterElement = document.getElementById('recruiter_' + submissionID);
    var consultantElement = document.getElementById('consultant_' + submissionID);
    var jobTitleElement = document.getElementById('JobTitle_' + submissionID);
    var impPartnerElement = document.getElementById('Imp_Partner_' + submissionID);
    var endClientElement = document.getElementById('EndClient_' + submissionID);
    var endClientLocationElement = document.getElementById('EndClientLocation_' + submissionID);
    var partnerNameElement = document.getElementById('PartnerName_' + submissionID);
    var partnerContactElement = document.getElementById('PartnerContact_' + submissionID);

    // Enable editing for the elements
    dosElement.contentEditable = true;
    recruiterElement.disabled = false;
    consultantElement.disabled = false;
    jobTitleElement.contentEditable = true;
    impPartnerElement.contentEditable = true;
    endClientElement.contentEditable = true;
    endClientLocationElement.contentEditable = true;
    partnerNameElement.contentEditable = true;
    partnerContactElement.contentEditable = true;

    // Add a CSS class to indicate editing mode
    dosElement.classList.add('editable');
    recruiterElement.classList.add('editable');
    consultantElement.classList.add('editable');
    jobTitleElement.classList.add('editable');
    impPartnerElement.classList.add('editable');
    endClientElement.classList.add('editable');
    endClientLocationElement.classList.add('editable');
    partnerNameElement.classList.add('editable');
    partnerContactElement.classList.add('editable');

    // Change the edit button to save button
    var editButton = document.getElementById('editbutton_' + submissionID);
    editButton.innerHTML = 'Save';
    editButton.onclick = function () {
        saveSubmission(submissionID,user);
    };

    initializeDropdowns(recruitersData, consultantsData, submissionID, user);
}


// Function to handle the save button click
function saveSubmission(submissionId,user) {
    // Get the elements that were made editable
    var dosElement = document.getElementById('dos_' + submissionId);
    var recruiterElement = document.getElementById('recruiter_' + submissionId);
    var consultantElement = document.getElementById('consultant_' + submissionId);
    var jobTitleElement = document.getElementById('JobTitle_' + submissionId);
    var impPartnerElement = document.getElementById('Imp_Partner_' + submissionId);
    var endClientElement = document.getElementById('EndClient_' + submissionId);
    var endClientLocationElement = document.getElementById('EndClientLocation_' + submissionId);
    var partnerNameElement = document.getElementById('PartnerName_' + submissionId);
    var partnerContactElement = document.getElementById('PartnerContact_' + submissionId);
    console.log(recruiterElement);
    console.log(consultantElement);
    // Disable editing for the elements
    dosElement.contentEditable = false;
    recruiterElement.disabled = true;
    consultantElement.disabled = true;
    jobTitleElement.contentEditable = false;
    impPartnerElement.contentEditable = false;
    endClientElement.contentEditable = false;
    endClientLocationElement.contentEditable = false;
    partnerNameElement.contentEditable = false;
    partnerContactElement.contentEditable = false;


    //Get the updates values from the editable elemnts
    var updatedSubmission = {
        S_DOS: dosElement.innerHTML,
        S_RecruiterId: recruiterElement.value,
        S_ConsultantId: consultantElement.value,
        S_ConsultantJobTitle: jobTitleElement.innerHTML,
        S_ImplementationPartner: impPartnerElement.innerHTML,
        S_EndClient: endClientElement.innerHTML,
        S_EndClientLocation: endClientLocationElement.innerHTML,
        S_ImplementationPartner_Name: partnerNameElement.innerHTML,
        S_ImplementationPartner_Contact: partnerContactElement.innerHTML
    };

    // Remove the CSS class indicating editing mode
    dosElement.classList.remove('editable');
    recruiterElement.classList.remove('editable');
    consultantElement.classList.remove('editable');
    jobTitleElement.classList.remove('editable');
    impPartnerElement.classList.remove('editable');
    endClientElement.classList.remove('editable');
    endClientLocationElement.classList.remove('editable');
    partnerNameElement.classList.remove('editable');
    partnerContactElement.classList.remove('editable');

    console.log(updatedSubmission);
    //Send the updated submission data to the server
    fetch(submissionId + '/', {
        method: 'PUT',
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-CSRFToken': getCookie('csrftoken'),
            'Accept': "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(updatedSubmission)
    }).then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                window.location.reload();
            }, 50000);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });


    // Change the save button back to edit button
    var editButton = document.getElementById('editbutton_' + submissionId);
    editButton.innerHTML = 'Edit';
    editButton.onclick = function () {
        editSubmission(submissionId,user);
    };
}
```

Sorry about the long post but I just want to make sure I present all the information.

I tried the usual select attribute and update the innerHTML attribute with another dropdown and but it doesn't seem to work. I even tried the disabled attribiute (as seen in my JS Code).I am open to any solution- either through a plugin or a more advanced JS code.